# How to add Icon to Menustrip bar in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhTMC.png)

Hi all, I am newbie in Tkinter, Can you teach me to add an Icon to Menustrip with Tkinter?

Comment: Check about the `image` and `compound` options of `.add_command()` function.  See official [document](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/menu.htm#M48).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.